# Fail to launch Application

Tags: iphone

error: failed to launch '/Users/imobdevtech/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/timesync-ajuwdrwsixqrnodrkmfmwjpptbmq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/timesync.app/timesync' -- failed to send the qLaunchSuccess packet

This is the error I get First time installing app into Devic.
It installs Perfectly but could not launch.
In second try it works perfectly.
can anybody help with this issue...

Comment: THANKS DEAR,I WAS IN HURRY, AND DON'T LOOKED AT THE SUGGESTIONS...

Comment: I have looked at the link but not suited to my condition as i have entitlement option is unchecked and also my code signing is seperate from developer and distribution

Comment: yes dear i cheked it out even i tried restarting device,but :(

Comment: I also faced similar problem in the past. The reason can be many. In my case, it was due to some wrong values in the info.plist file.

Answer (score 0):

at last i got my answer from one of the very beginner of this site.

Solution is to delete currently running app first from the taskbar of device (by double ressing home button of device)and then installing your new version.

B'cos of i m installing app in device which has already running app,it creates such problm.